# Bootstrap 3, Haml, and Rails 4 - Create dropdown from model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have two models, `Notification` and `NotificationPath`.

Each `Notification` has an `area` attribute that maps up to a `NotificationPath` areas.

So a `NotificationPath` has_many `Notifications`.

I have the following haml code in my `notification/new` view:

```
= f.input :area, :required => false, label: false, :autofocus => true, placeholder: 'Notification Area', input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
```

This creates a text field that you can type anything into, and it functions correctly. However, what I really want is to display a dropdown of all of the available `NotificationPath` areas. When you select that choice, the dropdown box should be filled with the selected text.

How can I do that using Haml and Bootstrap 3?

Comment: You want to show a dropdown containing available areas in `NotificationPath` and upon choosing one of it's option, you wish to change the `input text` field above to show that value? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: added the answer for that. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) tag or [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) to create a dropdown as:

```
= collection_select :dropdown, :notification_id, Notification.all, :id, :area, { allow_blank: "Select area..." }, { class: 'dropdown_notification' }
```

Note that I have used `dropdown` as the first parameter instead of `:notification` or `f.collection_select`, this is because you *do not* want this parameter to nest into your `:notification` parameters hash.

From the markup, note down the id of this field, it must be something like `dropdown_notification_id`.

In your javascript/coffescript, write a function to track the `change` in this dropdown, using that change populate your `input` `text_field` as:

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'change', '.dropdown_notification', (event) -> 
    #console.log(this)
    selected_value = $(this).children().filter(":selected").text()

    #now fill that value in input field as:
    $("input#notification_area").val(selected_value)
```

The code is not fullproof since I just wrote it by intuition, but it should give you very clear picture of what you may want to do to achieve it.

Hope it helps :)
Good luck!

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the explanation. Just what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome. I was fiddling with almost same thing few hours back; and this explanation perfectly fitted for your use :)